# Learning about the Interrupt system of the 8085 processor

Tags: interrupts, processor, 8085

I am trying to investigate the RST5.5, RST6.5, and RST7.5 interrupts on the 8085 microprocessor.

I want to find information about the to the type of interrupting signal used and the built in hardwired priority scheme,but finding resources explained in a plain and simple way is next to impossible...even the Intel documents are very hard to understand!!

Comment: Why are you using such an obsolete device?

Comment: I read that it was a good way to begin learning about microprocessors.

Comment: No one uses it any more. There are lots of newer devices that are in common use, and are much easier to use, such as PICs and AVRs.

Comment: Isn't it the basis for most modern processors though?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn about interrupt-driven programming by studying old processors, the Z-80 might be a better bet... one of its features was a better interrupt system.

I learned a lot of hard-won lessons by writing an interrupt-driven serial I/O handler for the thing!

But if you're really wanting to learn about interrupts, it might be better to use a CPU where you have easy access to a system for development and test.